# I'm trying to use tortoise-tts AI text to voice on Colaboratory, but keep getting the following error message when I try to upload my audio samples

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm using the AI text to speech tool called Tortoise:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NxiY3zHN4Nd8J3YAqFsbYaOB71IiLE04?usp=sharing#scrollTo=bt_aoxONjfL2

But when I get to the uploading my audio sample stage I get this error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPIgG.png)

I've tried changing the names and lengths of of the audio files, thought the lengths are already within the asked for range.

Any tips?`